# Is it possible to apply OData filter in the EF DBsets

Tags: .net, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am having the below model as the input from a Web API controller action

```
public class Query
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
    public int? Skip { get; set; }
    public int? Top { get; set; }
}
```

The filter used here is in the OData filter format.

I pass the same model to the data access layer to filter the entity in database. Is it possible to apply the `'Filter`, `OrderBy`, `Skip` and `Top` straight away on EF entities using the OData library in data access layer?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what exactly are you asking about, but I can assume that your problem is "parsing" part of that solution:)

And my answer is 'Yes', but it is a bit tricky.

You can use ODataQueryOptionParser class. With this parser you can for example parse filter expression to FilterClause.
With FilterBinder you can now parse FilterClause to Expression (predicate), and that expression you can use as argument for Where method from your dbset.
To make it all possible you have to provide EDM model to parsers.